# php cookie ignoring secure flag

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie with false in the secure parameter but when it is sent it always says secure/true. What could be causing my cookie setting to ignore that parameter?

```
setcookie( 'TEST', 'Testing', 0, C_PATH, C_DOMAIN, false );
```

Header:

```
Set-Cookie: TEST=Testing; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have the HttpOnly flag set - which is not on by default in PHP either. So it might be that these are added by your web server or something else between the client and PHP. Because PHP has no way of enabling these flags by default, you always have to set them explicitely for every `setcookie` call.

Yet I would recommend using both of them if you use them for PHP.

Comment: I tried using the httponly flag enabled and disabled and it still only comes across as a secure cookie..

Comment: Something else than PHP has to be modifying your cookies. I tried your example with the built-in PHP server (`php -S localhost:8000`) and `setcookie( 'TEST', 'Testing', 0, '/', null);` and received `Set-Cookie: TEST=Testing; path=/`